# ¿Cómo usar Auth::user() en el Api/Controller? (Laravel Vuejs)

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Laravel 7
Vuejs

Estoy tratando de usar Auth::user() en el API/controller pero siempre retorna null, Como puedo acceder a la data del usuario logueado en un api/controller.
Aquí dejo el código y el flujo del proceso:

----------------------Component .vue:-----------------------

```
  axios.get("/api/donaciones").then((response) => {
    this.donaciones = response.data;
    console.log(response.data);
  });
```

-------------------------api.php------------------------------

```
Route::resource('donaciones','Api\\DonacionController');
```

----------------Api/DonacionController-----------------

```
public function index()
{
    $user =  auth()->user();
    return response($user,Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```

He probado las siguientes opciones pero sin éxito:

```
Auth::user()
auth()->user()
$request->user('api')
auth('api')->user()
```

Qué me está faltando ?

Comment: Tendiras que crear in mixin que reciba la informacion del usuario logeado desde el un tag meta

Comment: Algun ejemplo que pueda ayudarme ? el usuario logueado lo puedo tener enviandolo como propiedad al componente pero lo que realmente quiero es poder usar auth()->user() en el api controller especificamente en el metodo index del controlador

Comment: creo que te entendi mall porque intentas retornar el usuario actualmente autenticado en una request de tipo JSON? estos datos los quieres mostrar algun componente?

Comment: Ya lo resolví muchas gracias, usé Passport de Laravel para generar un token y ese token lo envío al api controller para poder obtener el usuario que está logueado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

1. Instalé Passport para poder generar el token de acceso que se usa en el api controller para poder obtener al usuario que está logueado
   [1]: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport
2. El codigo usado en el componente para generar el token:

```
const data = {
  name: "Token Name",
  scopes: [],
};
let respuesta = {};
axios
  .post("/oauth/personal-access-tokens", data)
  .then((response) => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + response.data.accessToken,
      },
    };
    axios.get("/api/donaciones", config).then((response) => {
      this.donaciones = response.data;

      $(document).ready(function () {
        TableManageButtons.init();
      });
    });
  })
  .catch((response) => {
    // List errors on response...
  });
```

3. Código del api controller:

```
   public function index()
       {
           
           $user= auth('api')->user();
           $rol = Role::find($user->role_id);
   
           if ($rol->name == "administrador" or $rol->name == "comunicador"){
               $donaciones = Donacion::with("solicitud")->with('user')->with('centro')->with('user.gruposanguineo')->orderByRaw('FIELD(status,"pendiente", "aprobada","rechazada")')->get()->jsonSerialize();
           }else{
               $donaciones = Donacion::with("solicitud")->with('user')->with('centro')->with('user.gruposanguineo')->where('id',$user->id)->orderByRaw('FIELD(status,"pendiente", "aprobada","rechazada")')->get()->jsonSerialize();
           }
           return response($donaciones,Response::HTTP_OK);
       }
```

Comment: Que genial lo resolviste por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada